# Debugger watch window codepage

Tags: visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-debugging

When displaying a `char` buffer in the Watch window, how does the debugger determine which codepage to use? It's obviously neither the system default locale of the computer, nor the thread locale of the debuggee process.

Before VS2015, I recall this was not a problem. The system default locale was being used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For `char` strings, the **user** locale is being used, not the system default locale. For `char`s, it's system default. Bizarre.

To change the user locale, start Control Panel, Region and Language, Formats tab, choose the right language. VS picks up locale changes even without a restart.

It's a minor Visual Studio bug. If affected, vote for it here: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/2330394/debugger-watch-shows-char-strings-with-wrong-codepage